# How can we edit Laravel Auth redirect url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my project after authenticate the dashboard URL need to looks like "http://www.ct.dev/chistoper.martin_555/dashboard".

But now URL showing after authentication is "http://www.ct.dev/dashboard".

Please help me to edit url just like http://www.ct.dev/chistoper.martin_555/dashboard.

chistoper.martin_555 :  I need to take this name from database.

**AuthController.php**

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

**routes.php**

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'PublishprofileController@index');
});
```

**PublishprofileController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        session()->put('userID', Auth::user()->id);
        $confirmDetails   = User::select('confirmed_at')
            ->where('id', session()->get('userID'))
            ->first();
        return view('test.frontend')->with('confirmTime', $confirmDetails->confirmed_at);
    }
```

Comment: change your `$redirectPath = '/chistoper.martin_555/dashboard'` and make a route for it like `Route::get('/chistoper.martin_555/dashboard', 'PublishprofileController@index');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want your redirect path to be dynamic, this can be pretty complex and it might not even be possible. Instead you can do this in your `PublishprofileController`. This has the benefit of being more concise and can easily be changed down the line.

```
public function index()
{
    session()->put('userID', Auth::user()->id);
    $confirmDetails = User::select('confirmed_at')
        ->where('id', session()->get('userID'))
        ->first();
    return redirect(Auth::user()->name.'/dashboard');
}
```

Then in your `routes.php`:

Route::get('{name}/dashboard', 'PublishprofileController@show');

Then edit your `show` method to return the view. Obviously there's some more code you will have to write, that part is up to you, but this should get you on the right track

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.